# Problem when calling the helper function - Vue

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, helper

Main view:

```
<script>
import { testMethod1 } from "../helper";
export default {
  methods: {
    init(){
      console.log("Res:",  testMethod1());
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Helper:

```
import DataService from "../services/data.service";
export  function testMethod1() {
    DataService.getByPage()
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
          return response;
        })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
     })
}
```

Output:

From view:

> Res: undefined

From helper:

> 0: {_id: "60b621b4809e4304e04e7df4", desc: "aaa", …}
> 1: {_id: "60b621b4809e4304e04e7df5", desc: "bbb", …}
> (..)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @decpk is right. your not actually returning a response from your `testMethod1` function.  Try `return DataService.getByPage()...... blah...blah`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// See this is the same error

const incorrectFoo = () => {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => json)
}



const correctFoo = () => {
 return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => json)
}

const someOtherFoo = async () => {
 console.log('incorrect foo', await incorrectFoo(), 'correctFoo', await correctFoo())

}

someOtherFoo()
```

This method is executing a async call,

```
export  function testMethod1() {
    DataService.getByPage()
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
          return response;
        })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
     })
}
```

Now if you notice `DatasService` is a async call and that async call get to another context where it whenever get resolved returns `response` which mean `testMethod1` is not returning anything any way try this

```
export  function testMethod1() {
    return DataService.getByPage()
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
          return response;
        })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
     })
}

<script>
import { testMethod1 } from "../helper";
export default {
  methods: {
    async init(){
      console.log("Res:",  await testMethod1());
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Async didn't help, still returns undefined

Comment: have u added the `return` in befiore `DataService`

Comment: I didn't notice it, it works now, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

After importing the method from helper, you need also to declare it in methods section like:

```
<script>
import { testMethod1 } from "../helper";
export default {
  methods: {
    testMethod1, // this is same with testMethod1: testMethod1,
    init(){
      console.log("Res:",  this.testMethod1());
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: yeah because i just saw that we forgot to add this. before calling the method. Check my answer again

Comment: This will not work, problem `testMethod1` always get recognised so it's not required to add it to vue instance.